How to do smth before window will close if user has clicked red close button of window? Xamarin.mac
I have a main NSViewController object, which has buttons for calling other NSViewController objects. I would like to show the results of the user's work before the window (NSViewController) closes, when he gets tired and presses the red close button
I wanna get some func which will launching when user will have clicked the red close button of window

I've looked at a lot of answers to questions that match mine, but there were a couple of exceptions

The answers were for the Swift language
only parts of the codes were given. All without specifying where to insert them


To handle the window events, you (obviously) need an NSWindow object.
Once you have the NSWindow (let's call it wnd), then you need to follow these steps:

Implement the NSWindowDelegate with the windowWillClose() and/or windowShouldClose() handlers. For example:
[Register("NSWinDelegate")]
public partial class NSWinDelegate : NSWindowDelegate
{
    public override bool WindowShouldClose(NSObject sender)
    {
        //your code here.
        //return true to allow window to close. Return false otherwise.
        return <true or false>;
    }

    public override void WillClose(NSNotification notification)
    {
    }
}


Assign the delegate instance to the window object using the XCode visual editor or from the code (for example, in the NSWindowController.WindowDidLoad())
var winDelegate = new NSWinDelegate();
wnd.Delegate = winDelegate;



P.S. when working with xamarin/mac&ios you typically need (and you often will to do this) to be able to read the swift /obj-c code and translate it to the C#, so you might consider to investing some effort into learning these things a lot.
